# Swipe Buttons on bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, slideshow, slide

I just implemented a nice `ScreenSlide Activity` that swipe between pages both with the user's swipe gesture and with the `Next` and `Previous` buttons. I did so by attempting to reproduce the behavior of [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) tutorial.

My problem is that the `Next` and `Previous` buttons are always shown in the Action Bar, while in the animations of the tutorial they are shown at the bottom of the screen when in Portrait mode, and in the action bar only when in landscape mode.

This is what I want to obtain:

[image]

and this is what I get:

[image]

my `ScreenSlideActivity`:

http://pastie.org/private/zetuetehtvpa1gotn11ua

`ScreenSlidePageFragment`:

http://pastie.org/private/eqzt9dw1rc586rqapais2w

`activity_screen_slide.xml`:

http://pastie.org/private/vur5e7tz4ldo0fpz47ymbg

`frag_info_screen_slide_page.xml`:

http://pastie.org/private/qzmpeavktum4tc5jsg45ww

my Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "madapps.bicitourbo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/images'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

    //Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.5'

    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'

}
```

> **EDIT**

After a great deal of searching I found out that the slide buttons will only go down when the buttons would extend `FragmentActivity` and `android:theme=@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` is set in the manifest file, whereas apparently there isn't another way to obtain the same result while using the newest `AppCompatActivity`, requiring you using `Theme.AppCompat.Light` themes instead.

Any help with this issue would be appreciated